# Возврат пустой строки вместо ошибки в шаблонных строках?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Когда прописываю выборку данных из массива который например пустой то возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property text.

${data[0].text}
```

Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы возвращалась пустая строка, а то писать конструкции if else очень не удобно если много вложенных данных.

Использую модуль vm - метод runInContext.

Comment: только проверка.

Comment: можно обёртку замутить: `const p = (el, key, def = '') => (el && el[key] || def);`. И в коде писать: `${p(data[0], 'text')}`.

Comment: ${data[0] ? data[0].text ? data[0].text : '' : ''}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Условный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
${data[0]?data[0].text:""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Принятый ответ без сомнения верный, но если вдруг Вам будет лень писать во всех вхождениях тернарный оператор и условия позволяют, можно воспользоваться вот таким фокусом, который поддерживают шаблоны строк:

```js
var data = [{text:'hello'}, null]

let f = (s, ...v) => s.reduce((a,e,i) => a+e+(v[i]?v[i].text:''), '');

console.log(f` -- ${data[0]} -- `)
console.log(f` -- ${data[1]} -- `)
```

вместо применения собственно шаблона, все данные будут переданы в функцию `f`, где уже вручную можно провернуть конкатенацию с необходимыми проверками